# My domain stopped working, can you help me find out where I bought it?

Tags: domains

Back in 2008 I bought my domain name `sogaard.us`, and it has worked fine since then, but this Friday I stopped receiving emails and today I found out that my website on the domain is not responding.

I am trying to figure out what is going on, as I have gotten no emails for renewal or anything like it. But I have one problem I can not remember where I registered it. Is this something you can help me with? `http://whois.domaintools.com/sogaard.us`

Comment: Look at your billing reminder emails from 12 months ago?

Comment: There are nothing, the only email is have is from EPAG 4/19/12 and 4/19/13 asking me if my information is correct.

Comment: Do you still have the relevant emails from 2008? Credit card receipt?

Comment: Your server was hosted on 77.66.80.23? perhaps you could ask hostmaster@meebox.net if they know anything? http://meebox.net/en/contact/ also has live chat ...

Comment: Nope, i do only have emails back to about 2010, and there are nothing there about my domain name. I bought it for many years in advance, so i have not had to touch it for many years.

Comment: Yes but sadly is the domain not registered at meebox

Comment: meebox may be able to tell you *where* it was registered?

Comment: Doesn't http://www.enterprice.net (EPAG) manage your registration?

Comment: That would be my guess, but is seems that they are only a reseller.

Comment: Last Updated by Registrar: EPAG DOMAINSERVICES GMBH so they changed the registration (Domain Last Updated Date: Fri Mar 06 04:39:52 GMT 2015). They should be able to tell you *why*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS-Server is called as follows:

> Name Server: NS2.GRATISDNS.DK
>   Name Server: NS3.GRATISDNS.DK
>   Name Server: NS1.GRATISDNS.DK
>   Name Server: NS4.GRATISDNS.DK
>   Name Server: NS5.GRATISDNS.DK

gratisdns.dk is hosted by this company:
http://web.gratisdns.dk/omos

> [image: LD-logo.gif]
>   Larsen Daten ApS (CVR: 32.160.395) 
>   Flæsketorvet 68
>   1711 Kopenhagen V
>   Telefon: 46 90 32 32
>   Fax: 46 90 32 34

Maybe you remember this company name?

Answer (score 3):

```
 Created by Registrar:                        NETWORK SOLUTIONS INC
```

So maybe http://www.networksolutions.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

DNS, Hosting, and other things like that are not the same as the registrar. You can move all those -- your registrar is set until transfer. So, your registrar is http://www.enterprice.net/

You can find out things like this by using http://network-tools.com